# Android GCM not able to send notification to device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I followed the example from the following website to register device and subsequently send messages to the device.

http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139

I could both register and subsequently send notifications from the server to the device successfully.

However recently, it stopped working. I could still register but could not send notifications.

Any idea what's the issue? Did Google changed anything recently?

Comment: i think your gcm id is changed check it

Comment: @raj How do I checked? Isn't it the same id as shown in the Google Developer Console? I checked the project id and the server id are still the same.

Comment: you can login and check https://console.developers.google.com/project/igneous-future-726/apiui/credential?authuser=0

Comment: @raj Is it the one under Credentials? E.g. "6699999999999.apps.googleusercontent.com" I previously used the numeric portion (666....9999) as my client id.